# Function of two variables

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, calculus

What does a function of two variables f(x,n) that gives the equation of a line with a y-intercept of n and an x-intercept of 16-n, look like?

Comment: is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

Equation of a line

```
f[x_] := m x + c
```

so, for example, when x = 3

```
y = f[3]
```

> c + 3 m

When x = 16 - n

```
f[16 - n]
```

> c + m (16 - n)

This must equal n for the OP's solution

```
Solve[c + m (16 - n) == n, m]
```

> {{m -> (c - n)/(-16 + n)}}

Replace m in another equation of the line

```
g[x_] := (c - n)/(-16 + n) x + c
```

For various values of c and n

```
c = 1;

Show[Table[Plot[g[x], {x, -100, 100}], {n, 2, 4}]]
```

[image]

```
c = 3;

Show[Table[Plot[g[x], {x, -100, 100}], {n, 2, 4}]]
```

[image]

Forcing a function of the form f(x,n)

```
h[x_, n_] := (c - n)/(-16 + n) x + c

c = 3;
n = 4;

Plot[h[x, n], {x, -100, 100}]
```

[image]